# Finding the steady-state output value in an op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

Find the steady-state value of V<sub>o</sub> in the given circuit if V<sub>in</sub> = V<sub>p</sub>cos(ωt). What happens if V<sub>in</sub> is a DC voltage with the value V<sub>p</sub>?

Answer (score 2):

> *What happens if V<sub>in</sub> is a DC voltage with the value V<sub>p</sub>?*

For a steady-state input voltage, the capacitor becomes an open circuit and, you are left with the regular gain equation for an inverting op-amp. In your case this is: -

$$V_{OUT(DC)} = V_{IN(DC)}\dfrac{-(R_1+R_2)}{R}$$

Comment: Why capacitor won't play a role? Since Vin is A.C. the potential across capacitor is also changing?

Comment: For a capacitor, its current is \$C\cdot\frac{dv}{dt}\$ hence, for a steady voltage, dv/dt is zero hence the current through the capacitor is zero @user167102 and, your question was: *What happens if Vin is a DC voltage with the value Vp*

Comment: It is assumed that the voltage \$V_i\$ is DC, so capacitor becomes open circuit in steady state.

Comment: @AmitM yes, that's what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: But we have to find V_outpur if Vin = Vp cos(wt)...

Comment: You didn't ask that question. This is a **question** and **answer** site; you supply a **question** and, someone like me supplies an **answer**. You asked this: *What happens if Vin is a DC voltage with the value Vp?* @user167102

Comment: Andy Aka, if the input voltage is AC as in  \$V_{in} = V_pcos(ωt) \$.  then the capacitor has some impedance.The output value would change.

Comment: @AmitM if you want to ask that question then you should raise a new question. I only answer questions raised in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that the current trough resistor \$\text{R}\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-0}{\text{R}}\tag1$$

And we can see that that is the same current that flows trough resistor \$\text{R}_1\$, so we can write:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_{\text{R}}=\frac{0-\text{V}_\text{C}}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-0}{\text{R}}\tag2$$

For the capacitor we can write:

$$\text{I}_\text{C}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{C}}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}=\text{sC}\text{V}_\text{C}\tag3$$

And the current through resistor \$\text{R}_2\$ is given by:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{C}-\text{V}_\text{o}}{\text{R}_2}\tag4$$

Using KCL, we can see that:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_\text{C}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\tag5$$

So, we can solve for the output voltage and find:

$$\text{V}_\text{o}=-\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{sCR}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}}\cdot\text{V}_\text{in}\tag6$$

Using the convolution theorem of the Laplace transform, we can find the output voltage in the time-domain:

$$\text{v}_\text{o}\left(t\right)=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[-\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{sCR}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\cdot\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau\tag7$$

Comment: Is it better to do the solution without Laplace transform by using complex frequency (jw)?  I would have calculated the output voltage by calculating impedance of capacitor as (1/(jwc)) and using KVL, KCL. This is for AC input.